# Connection String to create in memory db with tcp server and tcpAllowOthers

Tags: java, h2

I know that we can create an in memory DB and share it over TCP the following way [1]:

Use connection string `"jdbc:h2:mem:db1"`and start tcp server:

```
final String[] args = new String[] {
"-tcpPort", "8092",
"-tcpAllowOthers","true" };

org.h2.tools.Server server = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
```

And then access this DB over `"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8092/mem:db1"`

But I should by able to inlcude the tcp server creation directly in in the connection string. Is this not possible? [somthing like `"jdbc:h2:mem:db1;TCP_PORT=8092;TCP_ALLOW_OTHERS=true"`]

[1]
https://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/share-an-h2-in-memory-database-among-several-jvms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently that's not possible.

There is [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode) but in-memory databases are not supported because of the following:

> The IP address and port of the server are stored in the file .lock.db, that's why in-memory databases can't be supported.

Consider opening a feature request at https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues if you have a justifiable use case.